# Can SO be immediately followed by a main verb?

Tags: conjunctions, clauses

> He often comes **and plays** with us.

> You can stay **or go** with us.

> She missed the bus, **so ran** all the way to school.

The first two examples are fine, but the third one seems weird and ungrammatical.

Is it necessary that the same subject (she) must be added to the second clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [coordinating conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_(grammar)#Coordinating_conjunctions) **so** usually indicates a consequence, unlike **and** meaning addition or accumulation. However, the following sounds much more natural

> She missed the bus **and** ran all the way to school.

and the causal connection between the two is plain.

A comma followed by a conjunction joins complete sentences to form a [compound sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_clause_structure#Compound_sentences), so if you insist on **so** as the conjunction, the following may please your editor slightly better.

> She missed the bus **so** ran all the way to school.

Natural-sounding alternatives are

> She missed the bus **and thus** ran all the way to school.

and of course the compound sentence

> She missed the bus**, so she** ran all the way to school.

Retaining **so** as in

> She missed the bus **and so** ran all the way to school.

still sounds stiff and formal, perhaps more so than with **thus**, again surprising to this native speaker.

Finally, you might emphasize the penalty of her lack of punctuality, as in

> She missed the bus, so she **had to** (or **was forced to**) run all the way to school.

Answer (score 1):

While the meaning is clear without 'she' being used again, in practice, you'll find that it often *is* used in both clauses. As a native speaker, I find this is the case in most (if not all) contexts.